# Single word for "finding company"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

This is my very first question here on `english.stackexchange.com`, so please don't bite me if I do anything wrong. Also sorry for my English, it's far from perfect.

I need a single word (or a short informal conversational phrase) for `"finding company"` (to do something together, opposite to spending time alone), like in "He had finally found someone to watch the movie with".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was thrown off by "a company", which means "a business". You mean "company" in this case. And How much shorter than "He found company to watch the movie with" or "he found someone to watch the movie with" would you like to have it?

Comment: Thanks for your corrections. And "he found someone to watch the movie with" is exactly what I mean, but I need a kind of short conversational phraseologism for that.

Comment: @meandre I can say that I've never, ever heard anything more concise than "found someone"

Comment: Friendship: A ship big enough to carry two in nice weather but only one in foul.

Comment: Your English is fine. Hope you find us to be good company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term **[buddy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buddy)** is a US term meaning (among other things)

> a person who does some activity with you

It is commonly paired with a descriptive term to indicate the shared activity

> She is my movie buddy.
>
> John is a golf buddy.

While your question suggests you are seeking a verb, you might consider combining obvious verbs with *buddy*, as in

> *seeking a movie buddy*
>
> *looking for a chess buddy*

Comment: Is there a single word alternative to "finding a buddy"? Or maybe some informal alternative to "find"?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but there is the phrase [*buddy up*.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/buddy?q=buddy-up#buddy__7)

Comment: Thanks! `Buddy up` is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Company is one word and can be used as a verb. So you don't need the extra 'finding' unless you are in search of someone. Here are a couple of examples that may help you twig the meaning and usage of the word in question.

> associate with; keep company with: *these men which have companied with us all this time.* ODE
>
> [ with obj. ] archaic accompany (someone): *the fair dame, companied by Statius and myself.* ODE

Comment: +1 I didn't know this sense... but OP wanted something "conversational"

Answer (score 0):

**companion**, **accompany.**
his travelling **companion** [noun]
the two sisters were to **accompany** us to London [verb]

**Sentences are copied from google search results of these words. They are not original.